# Web scraping with Selenium not capturing full text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to mine quite a bit of text from a list of links using Selenium/Python.

In this example, I scrape only one of the pages and that successfully grabs the full text:

```
    page = 'https://xxxxxx.net/xxxxx/September%202020/2020-09-24'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(page)

elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name('text').text

elements
```

Then, when I try to loop through the whole list of links (all the by day links on this page: https://overrustlelogs.net/Destinygg%20chatlog/September%202020) (using the same method that worked for grabbing the text from a single page), it is not grabbing the full text:

```
for i in tqdm(chat_links):
driver.get(i)
#driver.implicitly_wait(200)
elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name('text').text
#elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]').text
#elements = elements.text
temp={'elements':elements}
chat_text.append(temp)
```

driver.close()

chat_text

My thought is that maybe it doesn't have the chance to load the whole thing, but it works on the single page. Also, the driver.get method seems meant to load the whole given page.

Any ideas? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest working it offline with requests or driver.page_source (the html parsing I mean)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Could you show me what that would look like? thanks

Comment: After the `driver.get(url)` you can use `source = driver.page_source`. Afterwards, with BeautifulSoup you can parse it and use `.find_all('text') and that will return a list with all the occurences of text in the html

Comment: @CaseyCushing : Please post relevant HTML and your expected output for better response?

Comment: @CeliusStingher when I added that it only got the first page. is there something wrong with my loop?

Comment: @ggorlen  I already have the links for the logs on this page for each day. I am trying to loop through them and grab the text. Does that help? Thanks! https://overrustlelogs.net/Destinygg%20chatlog/September%202020

Comment: That helps, but I recommend editing the post to show that URL. Thanks!

Comment: @KunduK ^^ here is the site

Comment: @CaseyCushing : Check my answer. Let me know how this goes?

Comment: @KunduK I added a comment there

Answer (score 1):

The page is lazy loading you need scroll the pages and add data in the list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://overrustlelogs.net/Destinygg%20chatlog/September%202020/2020-09-30")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".text>span")))
height=driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
data=[]
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(1)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text>span"):
        if item.text in data:
            continue
        else:
            data.append(item.text)

    lastheight=driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if height==lastheight:
        break
    height=lastheight

print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I already the list of links (one of these for each day: https://overrustlelogs.net/Destinygg%20chatlog/September%202020/2020-09-30). The problem I am having is looping through these and getting the full text, it is only getting the partial.

Comment: The page is lazy loading you have to move each page and then capture data.

Comment: right, but it is confusing because when I only get the text from one page, it gets all the text just fine. It is only when I loop through all the links that it doesn't get the full text. Should I use the WebDriverWait? Why would it load for one page but not when it is looping through?

Comment: You need to use infinite while loop to scroll page. and grab each span tag contain until you reach bottom of the page.

Comment: I would extremely grateful if you would help me out with the code on that. Help please? thanks so much!

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Comment: @CaseyCushing : Check the updated answer. Its fetching  all data.