# Writing a while loop for selenium/python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I started this question off in a previous post: [Web scraping with Selenium not capturing full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432539/web-scraping-with-selenium-not-capturing-full-text/64433211)

If you look at the bottom of that page, I need to write a while loop that scrolls to the bottom of each page and grabs the full text.

This is what I have so far:

```
while True:

for i in tqdm(chat_links):
     driver.get(i)
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    try:
         elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name('text').text
         temp={'elements':elements}
         chat_text.append(temp)
    except:
     driver.close()
```

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Comment: What website is it and what is your expected output.

Comment: @arundeepchohan it is covered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432539/web-scraping-with-selenium-not-capturing-full-text/64433211

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647849/scroll-to-the-end-of-the-infinite-loading-page-using-selenium-python Look at how to infinitely scroll a page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to the end of the infinite loading page using selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647849/scroll-to-the-end-of-the-infinite-loading-page-using-selenium-python)